# Submit form in JSON with AJAX

Tags: jquery, python, django, json, forms

I am trying to submit a form in AJAX in JSON format.

But whenever the form is submitted I get redirect to the form action page.

**HTML**

```
<form id="acc" action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off">{% csrf_token %}
            <p>Username: {{accform.username}}</p>
            <p>Password: {{accform.password}} </p>
            <center><input type="submit" value="update" class="button" /></center>
        </form>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $("#acc").submit(function(){
        username = $(this).find("#id_username").val();
        password = $(this).find("#id_password").val();
        var arr = { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"), "username": username, "password": password};
        $.post("/myaccount/", arr,function(data){
            alert(data);
        }, "json");
        return false;
    });
```

An alternative to the code above I've also tried is:

```
$("#acc").submit(function(){
                username = $(this).find("#id_username").val();
                password = $(this).find("#id_password").val();
                var arr = { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"), "username": username, "password": password};
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/myaccount/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

I've also noticed that I only get redirected when getting the `csrftoken` cookie.

Why is that?

Comment: The `return false` should stop form submission.  The only thing I could suggest is to add `event` as a parameter in the submit function, and add `event.preventDefault();` inside the function.

Comment: @Archer Tried, no effect at all. But the problem seems to come from getting the `csrf` cookie

Comment: What happens if you type `getCookie("csrftoken")` into the console?

Comment: @Archer ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined

Comment: That'll be your problem then :)  Where is `getCookie` coming from?  Are you including all the scripts?

Comment: @Archer I think so, can you check UPDATE 3?

Comment: Check the answer I added below.  It suggests a common cookie plugin and a simple code change to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js) Jquery cookies library, which is the one I was using and @Archer suggested me as well then you do need to get the cookies as `$.cookie("cookie_name")`

If you do it like that whole function is working and I get no errors when posting data with AJAX.
Also return false is enough for stopping the form to submit. `event.preventDefault();` is not necessary.

The whole complete code then is:

```
$(function(){
            $("#acc").submit(function(){
                username = $(this).find("#id_username").val();
                password = $(this).find("#id_password").val();
                var arr = { "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $.cookie("csrftoken"), "username": username, "password": password};
                $.post("/myaccount/", arr,function(data){
                    alert(data.test);
                }, "json");
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Also, if you are including `{% csrf_token %}` in your HTML code then you can get the values from either the Cookie or the `<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">` it creates in the form.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think adding this line will prevent form from submitting while the function is computing:

```
$("#acc").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // LINE ADDED
    /* treatment here */
    return false;
});
```

Furthermore, just to avoid mixing the CSRF token with your data, you can call the following function before using any Ajax request:

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: After adding your whole code I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because when you use `getCookie` it isn't recognised as a function and therefore javascript stops running.  You need to replace the call to `getCookie` with a function that does exist.

Use this library...

**https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js**

Change the following line of code to read...

```
var arr = { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken"), "username": username, "password": password};
```

I'm assuming you've got the code from elsewhere and assumed `getCookie` is a valid function, when it isn't.

Comment: I was already using this library. But I found the problem, I needed to get the cookie as `$.cookie("cookie_value")`. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: That's okay - glad to help :)